# Vlookup in R to search column name in another data frame and fetching another column once column name is matched - R language

Tags: r, merge, vlookup

I have following data frame :

```
Claim failure Part csp_rate sml_rate
23     F1     P1    45      65
45     F2     P4    80      56
55     F3     P4    45      82
65     F1     P4    75      77
```

and another data frame (which has data in columns exactly same as column names of first data frame)

```
Threshold  weight similarity
70         1      csp_rate
75         2      sml_rate
```

I want my final data frame to be like following

```
Claim failure Part csp_rate sml_rate  weight
23     F1     P1    45      65         0
45     F2     P4    80      56         1
55     F3     P4    45      82         2
65     F1     P4    75      77         3
```

Here weight is sum of weight having similarity (from data frame 1) >= threshold (from data frame 2) e.g. 1,2,3 etc

Can you guys help? stucked at it since long time now.

proposed duplicate question is  about joining two dataframes using dplyr::left_join(). The condition to join is less-than, greater-than i.e, <= and > which in my (above) case isn't same.

Comment: ...almost, but there's the variable column to join on too. If I'm understanding correctly the column to join on in `df1` depends on the `similarity` entry in `df2`, which is more complicated than the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Seems like transforming `df1` to long would reduce the problem to the dupe (and aggregating/transforming back to wide after the non-equi join).

Comment: Yes, Gregor! So basically for columns in df1 (csp_rate and sml_rate) I need to retrieve threshold against these  rates which are values in similarity columns and then compute weight. I know its kinda complex to explain :(